# why Niederreiter cryptosystem is not a candidate in NIST PQC competition?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, mceliece, niederreiter

Seemingly, Niederreiter cryptosystem is faster than McEliece, and it can also be used to implement digital signature. Why isn't this scheme appear in NIST post quantum competition?

Answer (score 1):

Classic McEliece *is* using the Niederreiter T-OWF:

> The KEM is built conservatively from a PKE designed for OW-CPA security, namely Niederreiter’s  dual  version  of  McEliece’s  PKE  using  binary  Goppa  codes.

https://classic.mceliece.org/nist/mceliece-20201010.pdf

Comment: You might want to add that there's no Niederreiter signature scheme in the NIST competition because no one submitted such a scheme